# CakePHP access denied

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-routing

In CakePHP I have this configuration:

```
//Config/routes.php
Router::connect('/viewServices', array('plugin' => 'usermgmt', 'controller' => 'services', 'action' => 'viewServices'));

//View/Users/dashboard.ctp
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__("Services",true),"/viewServices")?>

//View/Services/view_services.ctp
//I put here the view..

//Controller/ServicesController.php
public function viewServices(){
....
}
```

Now I can't understand the reason why it doesn't works!

I can't see the "view_services.ctp". The server redirects me to the "access_denied.ctp" page, but in the "view_services.ctp" I didn't put any control about the authentication, so maybe I'm doing other errors. Can somebody helps me?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `$this->Auth->allow('viewServices');`

Comment: are you using Auth in your app controller?

Comment: "view_services" is for users.
I've also a "manage_services" for admin. In this second case, I put:

<?php if ($this->UserAuth->getGroupName()=='Admin') { ?>
then there is the view code and it works!

So, I'd like to do something like it, but for Users. I thought to delete the prevoius line because everybody can see this page, so I don't need the UserAuth. No?

Comment: Rename viewServices function to view_services

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't works. I have a really similar function that works using manageServices instead of viewServices, manage_services.ctp instead of view_services.ctp with the correct line in the routes.php.. It works! I'm going crazy!

Comment: I put all the code here:
https://gist.github.com/SirPilgrims

Comment: Are you useing ACL or Auth?

Comment: did you try  @CTravel solution?

Comment: I tried, but the problem is that I'm using the Usermgmt plugin and I'd like to extend it. This plugin use a custom AuthComponent called UserAuthComponent and the function "allow" doesn't exist.
Teorically it should works (like other pages) without "allow"

Comment: @IsaacRajaei not on his code example, but i always use it, for pages where users dont need to be logged in and it works...

Comment: So are you using AuthComponent with Usermgmt plugin? I don't remember the error but I didn't see well.. Tomorrow morning I'll try again and then I'll say you.. Thanks very much to everybody!

Comment: So, I tried to add the command that you suggest to view_services.cpt but it doesn't works (correctly, I think). I tried also in the dashboard.cpt, but I receive this error:


Missing Helper

Error: Usermgmt.AuthHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class AuthHelper below in file: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp/app/Plugin/Usermgmt/View/Helper/AuthHelper.php

<?php
class AuthHelper extends AppHelper {

}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_helper.ct

Comment: Hi everybody! I can't understand how to integrate AuthComponent in Usermgmt plugin. Can anybody helps me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing it:

```
//Controller/Component/UserAuthComponent.php
.....
//CHANGE IT:
//if(!$userGroupModel->isUserGroupAccess($controller, $action, $this->getGroupId()))
//WITH IT:
if(!$userGroupModel->isUserGroupAccess($controller, $action, 1))
```

In this way, it works!

Thanks to everybody!